# Determining the aggregates in this domain

Tags: java, c#, object-oriented, domain-driven-design

I'm working on an ordering system where we receive tab delimited files that look like this (I removed most of the columns for clarity):

```
      OrderId   OrderLineId    BuyerName   BuyerAdress   RecipientName     RecipientAdress

         1            1         John        123, Street      Doe              25, street
         1            2         John        123, Street      Doe              25, street
         1            3         John        123, Street     Michael           11, France
         2            1         Sam         66,Somewhere     Lily             25, Poland
         2            2         Sam         66,Somewhere     Dave             25, Russia
         ...
```

Applying **DDD** I primarily extracted few entities as shown in the image below:

[image]

Some facts about the data received in the files:

1. An **Order** must have a **Buyer** and a **Buyer** must have an **Order** .
2. An **Order** contains at least 1 **OrderLine** and each **OrderLine** must belong to an **Order**.
3. Each **OrderLine** must have a **Recipient** and each **Recipient** must have an associated **OrderLine**.
4. The status history for the **OrderLine** must be tracked by the system (hence the **Line History** entity)

**Questions:**

1. Which entity is the **aggregate root**? Most of the articles I read about DDD would put the **Customer** entity as its own aggregate root and the Order with its OrderLines as the other root. However, since the Buyer and Recipient can **NOT** exist by themselves how can they be treated as their own aggregate root?
2. Should OrderLines be a value object or an entity? I have seen some answers on numerous blogs suggesting the OrderLines should be a VO, but I don't see why it shouldn't be treated as an entity since its identity will be needed in its relation with the History entity.
3. Similarly the Line History should be modeled as entity or value object

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13191883/entity-in-entity-relationship-diagram (This is not an endorsement of the answers in *that* question.)

Answer (score 2):

I think you missed one thing in DDD. And that is relationship between entities is expensive and you should think twice before adding it. You only add entity relationship if it is completely necessary. In your case, Buyer has no need to have lists of his orders. And there is no need for Recipient having list of order Lines. There is no need for those to exist inside the entities, but they should instead be modeled inside the repository. So you can get orders of given buyer and order lines of given recipient.

Also, there can be as many aggregate roots as there are entities in the design. Nowhere it says to have single aggregate root in whole design.

If I go by my logic, then there are 3 aggregates and roots in your design : Buyer, Recipient and Order with Order lines and Line history.

2 and 3 : Yeah it is logical that Order lines would be entity thanks to the relationship to their history. But I think they should still be part of order aggregate.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your buyer and recipient are value objects as they have no identity outside the relationship to an order and order line. I would therefore say that Order is an aggregate root and also order history is an aggregate root that is updated from events that happen within the order aggregate. I cover this in my free DDD book https://leanpub.com/Practicing-DDD